# air application fullscreen trouble

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, fullscreen

I am working on an  adobe AIR application and having trouble with fullscreen.

When I  set the application in fullscreen 
 (`stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`)
the display freezes and nothing is being rendered. 
When I set it back to normal (by pressing esc) the application works fine.

thanks

---

sorry for not updating the post earlier.
the problem is solved. there were some issues with the graphics card on the computer I was working..
now everything works fine!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE`?

Comment: Hi, 

yes I tried this also but there is no difference..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some quick ideas :

- Try to define the `fullScreenSourceRect` before changing displayState ; by doing this, your graphic card capacities will be used to smooth the render.
  (Note that the hardware smoothing doesn't seems to work on AIR 2.0 beta)
- ...if you're using AIR 2.0 beta, try the last stable version.
- Create an empty AIR project, put a Button and an Image on the scene, and retry with this project, to see if the issue comes from your code or if it's something else.
- Take a look at which version of the Flex framework you're using, and test with another one.
- If the problem persists, you may try your application on an other computer.

Hope this will help.